# Use jQuery in external php file

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php file that I load into another php file with jQuery. This works, but the moment I start using jQuery in the 'external file', I get ERROR 500.
The reason I used this approach is because this is handy to refresh the data after an AJAX function.

This I have:

**test.php:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.29473.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).tooltip({
                items: ".plupic , .ingr",
                content: function() {
                    var element = $( this );
                    if ( element.is( ".plupic " ) ) {
                        var src = element.attr('src');
                        return "<img src='" + src + "' style='max-height: 300px; max-width: 300px;'>";
                    }
                    if ( element.is( ".ingr" ) ) {
                        var txt = element.text();
                        return txt;
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#kasticket').load('cart.php');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="kasticket"></div><!-- Load data with jQuery-->
```

**cart.php:**

I just do a select from the database and write some data to a table with echo();
This works perfectly, but the moment I want to use jQuery, I goes all wrong...(I know this for sure because the jQUery works in a local html file and putting this line in comment makes my php working again)

```
 echo("
     <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            if($('#L$MyAant').width() < 70) {
                $('.TR1$MyAant').show();
                $('.TR2$MyAant').hide();
            }else{
                $('.TR2$MyAant').show();
                $('.TR1$MyAant').hide();
            }
        });
     </script>
 ");
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

If its any help: http://www.itreflex.be/TestAcc/test.php (with currently the jQuery line in comment).

And this is [cart.php](http://www.itreflex.be/TestAcc/karretje.txt), exported to txt, it was to long to paste here.

Comment: dude ,   $('#kasticket').load(cart.php'); On this line , Opening Single Quote is missing

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake, in my code the single quote is there

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell without the full source code but I have got a couple of ideas:

First Error 500 should be the HTTP code for internal server error, which basically means that the error lies on the server, then on the PHP side.

Could it be possible that you are mixing up PHP and jQuery on some of your other statements not posted here?

Second, you missed a single quote on your line

```
$('#kasticket').load(cart.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cart.php remove the brackets after echo ... For example

```
echo "<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if($('#L$MyAant').width() < 70) {
            $('.TR1$MyAant').show();
            $('.TR2$MyAant').hide();
        }else{
            $('.TR2$MyAant').show();
            $('.TR1$MyAant').hide();
        }
    });
 </script>";
```

Try this above line in your cart.php and see if that works.